# How to get Text of a Button in limejs

Tags: limejs

I have tried to use 
    `var b = button1.getText()` to get the text of a button in limejs but it does not seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

A [Glossy Button](http://limejs.digitalfruit.ee/docs/symbols/lime.GlossyButton.html) does not have a getText method as is, but you could alter the library and create it if that's what you need. I'm not sure why you would want to get the text of a button however, it seems trivial to me as it's mostly hard coded. What you could also do is set a listener to the button which then in turn sets a variable to the text you initially placed in the button.

Please take a look at the documentation of LimeJS before asking questions like this, you could easily have spotted the problem :)